# Upgrade from Angular 11 to 12 causes peer dependency conflict

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I'm currently upgrading from Angular `11.2.14` to Angular `12.0.5` and I run into the following issue:

```
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"12.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@12.0.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   dev @angular/compiler-cli@"12.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^12.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.0.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"12.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR!   2 more (@angular/localize, ng-packagr)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Am I right assuming this is because there is a conflict between the version `12.0.5` and `12.0.0` and they are incompatible? All my dependencies have now the same version, why is there a conflict present?

**package.json**

```
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "12.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/animations": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/cli": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/material": "11.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "12.0.5",
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please check your global angular cli version

Comment: I get the same thing and looking at the message it is not obvious what the issue is as I would hope it just works and we dont have to faff around with this. I tried to do the "ng update @angular/cli @angular/core" from https://angular.io/cli/update, but I get another error "n unhandled exception occurred: Cannot locate bin for temporary package: @angular/cli."

Answer (score 23):

I had to use npm v6 to make a successful update:

```
npm -g i npm@^6
npm i
ng update @angular/cli@^12 @angular/core@^12
```

Comment: thank you! downgrading npm from v8 to v6 magically fixed it for me after several attempts to work around a bunch of errors

Answer (score 6):

I had got same error on every version angular update when i used official update guide https://update.angular.io/ and command npx @angular/cli@12 update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12.
After long googling and trying i found next way for angular and angular material update (example for 10 to 11 update):

```
npx @angular/cli@11 update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11
```

getting subj error

remove node_modules and package-lock.json

```
npm install
```

Git commit

```
ng update @angular/core@11 --migrate-only --from 10 --to 11
```

Git commit

```
ng update @angular/cli@11 --migrate-only --from 10 --to 11
```

Git commit

```
npx @angular/cli@11 update @angular/material@11 @angular/flex-layout@11.0.0-beta.33
```

Comment: thank you for this working solution. Just to note that if you appen `-C` to each update command then it will commit after each migration step automatically

Comment: interestingly: Above mentioned command `npx @angular/cli@11 update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11
` succeeded without error, while the command `ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11` from the official update guide failed.

Answer (score 2):

**Downgrad npm v6,** I tried bunch of commands after googling get successful now

```
npm -g i npm@^6
npm i
ng update @angular/cli@^12 @angular/core@^12
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue which was confusing as a beginner

I initially tried this command, but I just got another error

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

I then found this link https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20843 and one person said to do this global cli command, this seemed to have fixed the issue when creating a new project

```
npm i @angular/cli -g
```

I can now create my new project command e.g.:

```
ng new example --routing false --style css --skip-git --skip-tests
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing! I will try this out tonight and report it works

Answer (score -1):

Update your `tsconfig.json` and then run

```
sudo npm install --force
```